# Defining classes

Tags: c++

I have some big code line which I want to pack into define for fast using.

```
EventManager::get_mutable_instance().get<EventManager::KeyEvent>("KeyPressed").Call(EventManager::KeyEvent::ArgsType(localEvent.Key));
```

Here is **EventManager** is singleton class. I'd prefer to pass into define only **EventManager::KeyEvent** type and signal name **"KeyPressed"**. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact I don't like defines I would make a "wrapper" function like this:

```
public void call(EventType type, String whatToCall) {
    EventManager::get_mutable_instance().get<type>(whatToCall).Call(EventManager::KeyEvent::ArgsType(localEvent.Key));
}
```

Edit:
An untested define could look like:

```
#define call(Type,Name) \
EventManager::get_mutable_instance().get<Type>(Name).Call(EventManager::KeyEvent::ArgsType(localEvent.Key));
```

Edit2:
Im not really used to your code, but what would it more readable and debugable would be sth like this. (Be aware, the class names are not yours but I hope you can see what I mean)

```
Event event = EventManager::get_mutable_instance().get<type>(whatToCall);
ArgType argType = EventManager::KeyEvent::ArgsType(localEvent.Key);
event.call(argType);
```

Comment: yes always prefer using inline functions over defines (the code will be inlined if it is more performant or you force inlining). `#define` will always replicate the code what is not a good idea and you most of the time loose type checking and have trouble with repeated arguments with side effects what might create subtle errors...